# Why is the "not" operator not working (boolean)?

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

`while (isWeatherBeautiful && isDaylight && !(Rain) || temperature >= 60)`

Did I place the (!)operator and all the brackets right? All operators work fine and do what they should do, but the "not" operator keeps looping no matter "true" or "false". Any hints?

This is homework...which means I have to use (!) somehow. Otherwise I would just throw it out.

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) says that `isWeatherBeautiful && isDaylight && !(Rain) || temperature >= 60` is same as `(isWeatherBeautiful && isDaylight && !Rain) || (temperature >= 60)`. Is that what you wanted the expression to mean? --- I doubt it, since `isWeatherBeautiful && !Rain` is redundant, unless you think the weather can be beautiful when it is raining.

Answer (score 1):

A few rules

- expressions of this type are evaluated from left to right.
- expressions using `&&` are evaluated as a group, so `a || b && c` is 
  evaluated as `a || (b && c)` and not as `(a || b) && c`

Now considering your question, think of it like this.

```
if (a && b && !c || d) {
   // do something
}
```

- if `d` is ever true, then the expression will be true.
- if `d` is false, then the expression will only be true if `a, b, and !c` are also true.
- So if the weather is beautiful, it is daylight, and not raining, it will be true regardless of the temperature.
- if the temperature is >= 60, it will also be true regardless of the other criteria.

I can't tell you how exactly how to correct it since I don't know what your criteria are.  But here is a possibility.

```
while (isWeatherBeautiful || (isDaylight && !(Rain) && temperature >= 60))
```

- if the weather is beautiful, then nothing else matters so it stands on its own
- if it is daylight, not raining and relatively warm, then it is also a nice day

Here are truth tables for | (or) and & (and)

```
 +---+---+-------+      +---+---+-------+      
 | A | B | A | B |      | A | B | A & B |      
 +---+---+-------+      +---+---+-------+      
 | T | T |   T   |      | T | T |   T   |      
 +---+---+-------+      +---+---+-------+      
 | T | F |   T   |      | T | F |   F   |      
 +---+---+-------+      +---+---+-------+     
 | F | T |   T   |      | F | T |   F   |      
 +---+---+-------+      +---+---+-------+      
 | F | F |   F   |      | F | F |   F   |      
 +---+---+-------+      +---+---+-------+
```

Comment: You don't explain the main issue, i.e. that [operator precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) says that `&&` comes before `||`, in the same way that `*` comes before `+`.

Comment: Any ideas on how to work the (!) into this (or something similar)? I know it's redundant in my example but I have to use all three operators "and, or and not " somehow. It doesn't necessarily have to be a weather thing.

Comment: @Michael See my updated answer with a possible suggestion.

Comment: thanks, it works. Logical thinking is not my forte.